# Laravel Carbon cast datetime to set seconds to 00

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

If I have variables like this:

```
$arivalTime1 = '2020-06-05 15:52:27'
$arivalTime2 = '2020-06-05 15:52:55'
```

how can I convert these variables using Carbon to have the seconds displayed as 00:

```
$converted1 = 2020-06-05 15:52:00
$converted2 = 2020-06-05 15:52:00
```

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers has `startOfMinute()`

Comment: $arivalTime1 = '2020-06-05 15:52:27',
$value=Carbon::parse($arivalTime1),
dd($value),
the value reserve the second part ...

Comment: "_remove seconds_" or make them zero?

Comment: @kerbh0lz Make them zero :-)

Comment: @OMR Thank you, I have added this as an anwser, if you awnser too I shall remove mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is many ways to do it:

1- like  Vladimir verleg 's answer:

```
$arivalTime1 = '2020-06-05 15:52:27'
Carbon::parse($arivalTime1)->format('Y-m-d H:i:00');
```

2- using startOfMinute() method:

```
Carbon::parse($time)->startOfMinute()->toDateTimeString();
```

3- using create method witch gave you more control:

```
$value=Carbon::parse($time);
$wantedValue=Carbon::create($value->year,$value->month,$value->day,$value->hour,$value->minute,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @OMR for your solution given in the comments:

```
Carbon::parse($time)->startOfMinute()->toDateTimeString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse your date-string using Carbon and format it, setting the seconds part to `00`:

```
$arivalTime1 = '2020-06-05 15:52:27';
echo Carbon::parse($arivalTime1)->format('Y-m-d H:i:00');
```